# Timeout set in the web.xml is not working in java

Tags: java, jsf, listener, session-timeout

I am trying to set my application timeout on Tomcat 7 app server.First I am testing with my timeout as one minute in web.xml as

```
 <session-config>
       <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
  </session-config>
```

and I am using [HttpSessionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) to make sure my Timeout is working fine.I declared my sessionListener Class in web.xml .

```
public class HttpSessionChecker implements HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Session ID %s created at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
    }
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.printf("Session ID %s destroyed at %s%n", event.getSession().getId(), new Date());
    }
}
```

and In web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.test.util.HttpSessionChecker</listener-class>
</listener>
```

But when start my server and launch my application I see session is initiated on the Login page only .

```
Session ID 934073ED5E9933158995EE5EB680D3F7 created at Wed Nov 07 09:39:13 PST 2012
```

and when I stay Idle for more than a minute or some times more than five minutes cause Tomcat don't fire Timeout immediately in my application and click on something in my application Session is not Expired.Still I am able to navigate another page.But When I am stay Idle on the login page or logged-out I see the session is destroyed. But when once Login is done and when I am inside the application session timeout is not happening. I see

```
Session ID 934073ED5E9933158995EE5EB680D3F7 destroyed at Wed Nov 07 09:42:13 PST 2012
```

What am I doing wrong? And even after I mentioned `<session-timeout>` in `web.xml` do I need code `session.invalidate`somewhere in Code? How Can I redirect to `login.xhtml` in session destroyed in JSF?

Comment: Where is the logic that creates your session? Where do you first access a `@SessionScoped` bean? Do you first check for active sessions before honouring a request or you silently create a new one?

Comment: Check [Session Timeout Handling on JSF AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11203195/1065197)

Comment: @kolossus...When I launch my application,login page will hit Login Bean which is Session Scoped. And at the time of login we are not checking anywhere !(session.isNew()).I guess it's creating a new session.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your doing nothing wrong. A background thread will check every x minutes for,when the sessions expire. This is container specific. Ie it is not guaranteed to be expired after the time you specify. I know in tomcat you can easily modify this check interval in the server.xml file.

Comment: But why my session is not destroyed when I am logged in and Inside the application?

Comment: same reason. If the check interval is larger than the timeout value then it is not going to be destroyed yet.

Comment: @MarcusBlackhall where in the server.xml do I have to set the interval?

Comment: @MarcusBlackhall : I'm also looking for the same answer.

Comment: Found it. It's `<checkInterval>` config. See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/manager.html