# Session timeout is not working

Tags: session, servlets, session-timeout

Currently I have added this in my web.xml

```
    <session-config>
      <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
   </session-config>
```

But after one minute session is not getting expired,
I don't know whats wrong can anyone let me know where i'm doing wrong

Comment: Some more detail will be appreciable check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/13276873/3514144

Comment: You forgot to tell the servlet web.xml version, the server make/version and how exactly you attempted to observe the timeout. Now no one in the world can reproduce your problem because it works just fine based on solely the information provided in the question and tested on latest servlet/server versions available and observed with the most logical way.

Comment: @BalusC  Thanks for telling..Actually im very new to this..im learning..Will it help?                                                                            `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">`