# Handle ViewExireException/ajax and display a Primefaces dialog

Tags: jsf-2, exception, dialog, primefaces, viewexpiredexception

I don't redirect or forward my user to another page. So when the my `SessionExpiredExceptionHandler` (extends `ExceptionHandlerWrapper`) handles the ViewExireException. I want the user to stay on the same page and display a PrimeFaces Dialog. For notifying that the session has expired and that the user needs to login again (dialog based). I am use Servlet 3.1 functions to login/logout user and `Basic/file` for auth-method to map the users to different system roles.

What is happening now is that the View/page get refreshed after 2 min, but the session doesn't get invalidated. That only happens the second time when the page refreshes, after 4 min.

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>2</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

**Edit:**
Which is refreshed by the meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="#{session.maxInactiveInterval}" />
```

How can I make `SessionExpiredExceptionHandler`invalidate the session object (Servlet logout) when the Exceptions occur the first time, and how can I invoke a JavaScript (expireDlg.show()) on the client to display a PrimeFaces dialog ?

I have looked at some other threads but not found a viable solution.
[Session time-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request)

SessionExpiredExceptionHandler

```
    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException {
    for (Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> i = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
        ExceptionQueuedEvent event = i.next();
        ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
        Throwable t = context.getException();
        if (t instanceof ViewExpiredException) {
        ViewExpiredException vee = (ViewExpiredException) t;
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        Map<String, Object> requestMap = fc.getExternalContext().getRequestMap();
        NavigationHandler nav = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();                

        try {
            requestMap.put("currentViewId", vee.getViewId());

            nav.handleNavigation(fc, null, "Home");
            fc.renderResponse();

        } finally {
            i.remove();
        }                                
        }
    }
    // At this point, the queue will not contain any ViewExpiredEvents.
    // Therefore, let the parent handle them.
    getWrapped().handle();
    }
```

web.xml

```
<exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/home.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution worked for my case. It seams that Primefaces (3.3) is swallowing the ExceptionQueuedEvent. There are no Exception to handle when my ViewExceptionHandler gets called. So instead I used the `p:idleMonitor` component with event listner. I also removed the meta refresh tag.

```
<p:idleMonitor timeout="#{(session.maxInactiveInterval-60)*1000}">
        <p:ajax event="idle" process="@this" update="sessionMsg" listener="#{userController.userIdleSession()}" />
        <p:ajax event="active" process="@this" update="sessionMsg" listener="#{userController.userActiveSession()}"/>
</p:idleMonitor>
```

One weird thing is if the `timeout`is excatly the same as the `web.xml`session time-out parameter, the listener won't be invoked.

Bean functions

```
public void userIdleSession() {
    if (!userIdleMsgVisable) {
        userIdleMsgVisable = true;
        JsfUtil.addWarningMessage(JsfUtil.getResourceMessage("session_expire_title"), JsfUtil.getResourceMessage("session_expire_content"));            
    }
}

public void userActiveSession() {
        if (!userSessionDlgVisable) {
            userSessionDlgVisable = true;                     
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("sessionExipreDlg.show()");            
        }
    }
```

The dialog (`sessionExipreDlg`) called the redirect instead of using navigation handler to get new scope and refresh the page.

```
public void userInactiveRedirect() {
        FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        userIdleMsgVisable = false;
        userSessionDlgVisable = false;
        sessionUser = null;         
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        JsfUtil.findBean("homeController", HomeController.class).clearCurrentValues();        
        try {
            fc.getExternalContext().redirect(JsfUtil.getApplicationPath(request, false, null));            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            BeanUtil.severe(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: And what if the user did not click anywhere on the page just moves the mouse (example with scrolling) until the session expires. After it makes a click on a button for example. Then an ViewExpiredException will be thrown.

Answer (score 2):

> *How can I make SessionExpiredExceptionHandler invalidate the session object (Servlet logout) when the Exceptions occur the first time*

The session is supposedly to be *already* invalidated/expired ([otherwise a `ViewExpiredException` wouldn't be thrown at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969)), so I don't see how it's useful to manually invalidate/expire it yourself. But for the case that, you can invalidate it as follows:

```
externalContext.invalidateSession();
```

---

> *and how can I invoke a JavaScript (expireDlg.show()) on the client to display a PrimeFaces dialog ?*

You can use the PrimeFaces [`RequestContext`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/3.4/org/primefaces/context/RequestContext.html) API to programmatically instruct PrimeFaces to execute some JS code on complete of ajax response.

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("expireDlg.show()");
```

Don't forget to remove the navigation handler block from the exception handler if you actually don't want to navigate.

Comment: That I figured out, to comment out the navigation part. But at the moment the handler doesn't get called at all. The page only get refreshed, but the locally store SessionUser is still valid?

Comment: You mean, the exception handler is never constructed/invoked? Did you register its factory in `faces-config.xml` as expained in the blog article where you found this kickoff example?

Comment: Acctually the ExceptionHandler get called several times for every request. Even if there are no Exceptions.

Comment: I've done what you have suggested, I've removed navigation block, but I got NullPointerException: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14606828/how-to-handle-viewexpiredexception-by-showing-javascript-alert