# Primefaces: Default oncomplete method for all ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery, primefaces

I am trying to configure an oncomplete method for all ajax requests so that I can handle session timeout.

I tried adding the following script but it didn't work the same way as setting oncomplete property for p:ajax element. It wouldn't execute each time an Ajax request is made.

```
$.ajaxSetup({method: post,
    complete: function(xhr, status, args){
        var xdoc = xhr.responseXML;
        if(xdoc == null){
            return;
        }
        errorNodes = xdoc.getElementsByTagName('error-name');

        if (errorNodes.length == 0) {
            return;
        }

        errorName = errorNodes[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
        errorValueNode = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('error-message');
        errorValue = errorValueNode[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        alert(errorValue);
        document.location.href='${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login/login.jsf';
    }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to implement this by wrapping Primefaces AjaxUtils method.

```
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxUtilsSend = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send;

   PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxUtils.send = function(cfg) {
      if (!cfg.oncomplete) {
         // register default handler
         cfg.oncomplete = oncompleteDefaultHandler;
      }
      originalPrimeFacesAjaxUtilsSend.apply(this, arguments);
   };
```

Answer (score 6):

PrimeFaces newer versions (using PF 5 here)

```
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxUtilsSend = PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.send;
PrimeFaces.ajax.Request.send = function(cfg) {
    if (!cfg.oncomplete) {
        cfg.oncomplete = doYourStuff;
    }
    originalPrimeFacesAjaxUtilsSend.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

Just to keep it somewhere, tried to find at stackoverflow but only older versions..
hope someone find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

In primefaces there is component `ajaxStatus` which you can use for this purpose. Read documentation to see some more details about it, but for your use-case it can be something like this:

```
<p:ajaxStatus oncomplete="ajaxStatusHandler(xhr, status, args)"/>
```

and you can use your JavaScript function as is:

```
function ajaxStatusHandler(xhr, status, args) {
  // your code ...
}
```

NOTE: this method can be used just for global AJAX requests (which is default in PrimeFaces), also, as I know, cross-domain script or [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (JSON with padding) requests can't be global.