# How can I notify the user that the session time has elapsed?

Tags: session, jsf-2, primefaces, managed-bean

I created a method in the bean

```
public void checkSessionLife() {
        if (FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false)==null) {
            System.out.println("*\n");
            System.out.println("destroyed");
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("sessiongr", new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "erer", "errrrrrrrrr"));
            RequestContext requestContext = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
            requestContext.update(Arrays.asList("hreaderForm:sessiongr"));
        }
    }
```

and in my `PgTemlate.xhtml` i add a `<p:poll>` to update a `<p:growl>`

```
<p:poll interval="5" listener="#{accessBean.checkSessionLife()}" process="@this" global="false"/>
                <p:growl id="sessiongr" showDetail="true" sticky="true"/>
```

the problem is that the activity is seen as `<p:poll>` activity sessions
There he has another method to notify the user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the scope of accessBean? If it's anything less than application scope, I believe the function will fail to run, because JSF cannot find the bean.

Nonetheless, this isn't the recommended method for handling session expirations. For the preferred one, see [BalusC's method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request).