# No ajax action fired after session invalidate

Tags: ajax, jsf, session, primefaces, cas

We have a JSF webapp with Primefaces 4.0 and CAS Single Sign On.

When a user requests an ajax action (by clicking a p:commandButton or similar component with ajax=true) after he has lost his session because SSOut in another tab, nothing happens, no response from server or action is triggered. 
We need to manage that situation to inform the user that his session is no longer available, by showing a dialog or redirecting him to home or a custom page, but we don't know how.

ajax=false solves the problem, but this is not what we want to do.

No ViewExpiredException is thrown.

EDIT:
We had already read and tried [this BalusC's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206114/4074715) without success. No Exception is thrown and Handler has nothing to do. Note that isn't an Expired Session or Invalidated by TimeOut session, is just an explicit session.invalidate caused by Cas Sign Out in another tab.

We also tried javascript jsf.ajax.addOnError() solution, and again nothing to capture.
Only p:ajaxStatus onError event catches something, but no way to identify that particular error. Even overriding ajaxStatus javascript function, error data parameter is undefined... 
Also, p:log says "Request return with error:error." but, which error is it? how do we identify it?
We are stuck on this issue...

Answer (score 2):

This has been discussed many times, and as far as know there aren't any out-of-the-box solutions yet. One solution is to add a custom `ExceptionHandler` as stated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11206114/4074715).

Another option is to register client error handler using `jsf.ajax.addOnError(...)`, and to handle this exception in it. You might need some server code to add a custom header in case session is invalid, which you would use in error handler to be able to differentiate that specific case from other errors.

Comment: Hi @Predrag, thanks for your response. We had already read and tried that BalusC solution without success.

Comment: I understand, one thing you can try is to have a servlet filter through which every request will go (maybe even just ajax, but no need to make it complicated). In this filter you can add some custom header whose value will depend on session validity (which you can check on server side). Something like `session-valid: true/false`. With that, `addOnError` handler would be able to identify this particular state.