# Default jsf errorpage is not displayed

Tags: jsf

I have defined an error-page in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.RuntimeException</exception-type>
        <location>/errorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/errorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

but no redirect to errorpage.jsf is visible.

I see in the logfile:

```
UT005023: Exception handling request to /calculation/secure/adminPaper.jsf:
```

The exception here is for example

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.transaction.RollbackException: ARJUNA016053: Could not commit transaction.
```

need more information?

best regards

Heiko

Comment: Are you sending Ajaxical requests? If not and you are not redirected to the configured error page then, try setting [the buffer size](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11768021/1391249) to a bigger value.

Comment: You can add `filter` and react on **any** exception in your application (with redirection to error page)

Comment: I increased the buffer size as in the other thread - but it did not help. I also have a template - but removing has no effect. Would it probably be better, to include the errorhandling in the template?

Comment: If the exception happens during an ajax request, JSF won't redirect to the error page. That's a tricky part of the framework which is fully covered by the Omnifaces auxiliar library, which offers a [full ajax exception handler](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) for this cases. Anyway, it would be nice to know when are you getting this exception...

Comment: The errors can occur in Ajax as also in non Ajax requests. I use Primefaces and don't want to use another framework for error handling. Another idea is to use the Primefaces errorhandler in my default template, but that also does not work.