# How to fix injection of FacesContext on error page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, jsf-2.3

I've got JSF 2.3 WAR project with standard JSF exception handling. Any error in request is dispatching to the jsf error page which is configured in`web.xml`. I'm also use new JSF 2.3 [improved CDI support](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/p/jsf-23.html#1316) to inject FacesContext.
The problem is when on ordinal page is some unhandled error and jsf dispatch the request to the error page. Then I get an `IllegalStateException` in `com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased`.

After some debugging I've realized that the problem is when I inject `FacesContext` in both views. The key problem in this situation is that injection of `FacesContext` is stored in Request Scope and when it is injected again on error page, `FacesContext` stored in Request scope is already released and obsolete as it is created again when error page is created.

To show this situation I made small demo project running on WildFly 16.0.0.Final with simple `index.xhtml` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<body>
<p>
    <h:outputText value="Index page"/>
</p>
<p>
    <h:outputText value="Is postback: #{facesContext.postback}"/>
    <h:outputText value="#{index.throwException()}"/>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

and `error.xhtml`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
<body>

<h:outputText value="Error page"/>
<h:outputText value="Is postback: #{facesContext.postback}"/>

</body>
</html>
```

My `web.xml` is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
        <location>/error.jsf</location>
    </error-page>

    <default-context-path>/</default-context-path>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsf</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

After trying to show `index.jsf` I've got the following exception:

```
14:26:12,688 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005022: Exception generating error page /error.jsf: javax.servlet.ServletException
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:725)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:451)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:274)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchToPath(ServletInitialHandler.java:209)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.spec.RequestDispatcherImpl.error(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:428)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:331)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@16.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1502)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:364)
    at io.undertow.core@2.0.19.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.3.3.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.assertNotReleased(FacesContextImpl.java:692)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.context.FacesContextImpl.isPostback(FacesContextImpl.java:185)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at javax.el.api@1.0.13.Final//javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:241)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:156)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
    at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.parser.AstDeferredExpression.getValue(AstDeferredExpression.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:68)
    at org.glassfish.javax.el@3.0.1-b08-jbossorg-1//com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.core@3.1.0.Final//org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(WeldValueExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:73)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:170)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:157)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:140)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:181)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:328)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:143)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:595)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1654)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1650)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:468)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:170)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:102)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:76)
    at com.sun.jsf-impl@2.3.9.SP01//com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:199)
    at javax.faces.api@2.3.9.SP01//javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.executeLifecyle(FacesServlet.java:708)
    ... 34 more
```

On the end I'm not sure if this is the JSF bug or it is made by design and I should use it in different way?

Comment: Throwing an exception in a getter is not the best design. What if you add a button with an action and throw it from there? (Not saying that is the solution but just to see if it makes a difference)

Comment: Oh and please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10534187/why-use-a-jsf-exceptionhandlerfactory-instead-of-error-page-redirection

Comment: In this demo project I'm just simulate an exception during Rendering phase. In my real project I'm using omnifaces and their FullAjaxExceptionHandler and got the same result.

Comment: Ok, good additional information. I van try tomorrow to see what happens in my environment.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410007/jsf-2-global-exception-handling-navigation-to-error-page-not-happening. Take a look at the comments of BalusC (guy from omnifaces)

Comment: I have the exact same problem in my web application. The problem persists to happen on Wildfly 17.0.1, i.e. Mojarra 2.3.9.SP02. Falling back to JSF 2.2. seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately the problem persists in Wildfly 19 / Mojarra 2.3.9.SP06. Did you find a satisfactory solution to this problem?

Comment: I didn't find any useful solution. As I remember I didn't use @Inject for FacesContext in my backing been, instead I call FacesContext pragmatically.