# Exception handling for Ajax requests in JSF using Omnifaces : always showing Status Code 200 instead of 500

Tags: jsf, omnifaces, dynatrace

we are currently adding a monitoring solution (Dynatrace) to our JSF web application. The monitoring solution checks for status codes that indicate an error to flag a problem in a user session. We are trying to use Omnifaces FullAjaxExceptionHander (see http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler) to handle Ajax exception and render an error page. As you can see from the screen shot Omnifaces sets an error code of 500 but the status code on the POST shows up as 200 in Chrome. As Dynatrace doesn't see an error status code it does not flag this on the user session.

Any idea why the status code is not set on the response? I thought I saw it briefly come up with a status code of 500 on the POST in our system but now it is only showing 200 again. That's when I tried the example from the Omnifaces showcase and there I am only getting the 200 has well.

[image: Screenshot of Omnifaces Showcase and status code received by browser]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because it's technically a successful **Ajax** response. I.e. it has successfully delivered the error page content as part of `<partial-response>` in the Ajax response XML body.

If the Ajax response would have status 500, then JSF wouldn't have parsed the Ajax response XML at all, but instead invoked the `onerror` handler which in turn fires any registered custom client side code. This is where things get complicated as it by default doesn't render anything while the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` really wants to utilize the existing JSF Ajax rendering logic.

Your best bet is to check if your monitoring service offers a Java based API to manually notify the error condition. And if so, then override one of the `FullAjaxExceptionHandler` methods to ping it. The `shouldHandleExceptionRootCause()` is a good candidate. There you can if necessary also perform an `instanceof` check on the exception to skip certain ones.

I'm not familiar with Dynatrace, but in case you're using [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/), this is how it would look like:

```
import com.newrelic.api.agent.NewRelic;

public class CustomExceptionHandler extends FullAjaxExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldHandleExceptionRootCause(FacesContext context, Throwable exception) {
        try {
            NewRelic.noticeError(exception);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            // Log a WARN line
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Finally create a custom `ExceptionHandlerFactory` for it and replace the `FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory` in `faces-config.xml` with it.

Comment: In the 'epic fail'  case, I see a `<partial-response id="error">` couldn't this be done on the other responses that are a result of being processed by the full ` FullAjaxExceptionHandler`? Or something like an` x-omnifaces-FullAjaxExceptionHandler: true` header being set in the response? Not sure if it is useable in the case of OP, but just a small thought

Comment: @Kukeltje: sounds doable.