# Primefaces Schedule component - handling exception during lazy model load

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

When loading events for my PF schedule it is sometimes possible that exception occures. Is it posiible to somehow notify the user (using growl component) that such a situation occured?

EDIT:

This is how the exception is caught:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Sample error message", "Sample Error"));
    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("scheduleForm:scheduleGrowl");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And this is the part of the xhtml where the schedule component is defined:

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <h:form id="scheduleForm">
            <p:growl id="scheduleGrowl" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" sticky="true"/> 
            <p:schedule value="#{scheduleController.scheduleModel}"
                view="agendaDay" slotMinutes="15" resizable="false"
                draggable="false" firstHour="8"
                locale="${localeResolver.staticLocale}"
                axisFormat="${localeResolver.defaultTimeFormat}"
                timeFormat="${localeResolver.defaultTimeFormat}"
                >
            </p:schedule>

        </h:form>
    </ui:define>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the exception-sensitive code in a `try-catch` and use [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29) in the `catch` to add a message to the context.

E.g.

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (SomeException e) {
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(
        FacesMessage.SEVERITY_FATAL, e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage()));
    // Log the exception as well?
}
```

If you have however no control over this, then you'd need to create a custom [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html). Some hints can be found in this answer: [What is the correct way to deal with JSF 2.0 exceptions for AJAXified components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components) You don't necessarily need to show a full error page (although this is preferable as this kind of exceptions are usually unrecoverable, assuming that this is really no bug/misconfiguration in your code), you could also add a message to the faces context in there.

Comment: I have thought about that in the first place. I do not know however how to update the <p:growl> or <p:messages> component. I have tried `RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("scheduleForm:scheduleGrowl")` but this does not seem to work properly.

Comment: Set its `autoUpdate` attribute to `true`. Note that it won't be updated if the ajax response is different/malformed due to an uncaught exception. So it really need to be caught and not be thrown through.

Comment: Still no luck, exception is caught and not "rethrowned". I have posted code samples above

Comment: Apparently it's caught at the wrong moment. When exactly is that method invoked? Not during rendering of the view, I presume? That would otherwise explain the behaviour.

Comment: Excatly yes. I am ready to take the punishment :). I am quite new to JSF. So why is it happening?

Comment: Either move the `<p:growl>` to after the `<p:schedule>`, or, better, do the initialization job in bean's (post)constructor instead of a getter method. JSF getter methods should be free of business code.