# Add message from PhaseListener

Tags: jsf, error-handling, primefaces

I got some uncaught exception basically from an SQL operation via Primefaces AJAX call. Interestingly this uncaught exception APPEAR on FireBug's JavaScript secion as error:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response><error><error-name>class javax.faces.el.EvaluationException</error-name><error-message><![CDATA[Transaction rolled back]]></error-message></error></partial-response>
```

and on the server.log with all stacktrace and everything.

But I am unable to to bring it to the user attention without redirecting them to a separate error page (and lost all input data).

The proper way to handle this to create validator, which I will do, but there are always possibility of unaware database problem which will only appear doing the SQL operation. So I am only talk about no validator situation.

Let say I have this JSF snippet.

```
    <h:form>
        <p:messages />
        <..... primefaces (AJX) some button .... action="bean.save()" />
    </h:form>
```

and the bean.save();

```
  public void save()
  {
    try
    {
       em.merge(this.data);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       // never been in here EVEN if the data can't be merge for some constraint breaking reason.
    }
  }
```

If there is an database error, we will not see it until the transaction ends (AFTER save()) so I can't catch it. (This is confirmed with debug walk through and the fact that adding "em.flush()" here make the whole things works).

After looked left and right, I created a PhaseListener and I am able to get the exception. However, I am unable to show that exception on <p:messages />

```
    public void afterPhase(final PhaseEvent event)
    {
        final Iterable exceptionEvents = event.getFacesContext().getExceptionHandler().getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents();
        for (final ExceptionQueuedEvent exceptionEvent : exceptionEvents)
        {
            // This print out goes (found in server.log).
            System.out.println("Problem: " + exceptionEvent.getContext().getException());
            // But this message does not.
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,"Problem", "Problem: " + exceptionEvent.getContext().getException()));
        }
    }
```

Any advice is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`PhaseListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) is not the right place to handle exceptions. You should be using an [`ExceptionHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExceptionHandler.html). The only other change you need to make in the code is that you should use `Iterator` to iterate over the exceptions and use `Iterator#remove()` to remove the handled exception from the queue. Otherwise it will still be handled by the default exception handler in flavor of that ajax response which you're seeing.

#### See also:

- [What is the correct way to deal with JSF 2.0 exceptions for AJAXified components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components)