# How to get a different error page for different PROJECT_STAGE in JSF

Tags: jsf, custom-error-pages

I want to show detail exception along with stack trace on error page if the project stage is development

web.xml entry -

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

else if Project stage is Production then I want to show a custom message to user.

web.xml entry-

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Production</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: What if add a key in prop file and read it?

Comment: @VinayHegde can we do it onload, I mean when the application loads 1st time?

Comment: create a costum exceptionhandler ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410007/jsf-2-global-exception-handling-navigation-to-error-page-not-happening))

Comment: Any feedback on the answer?

Answer (score 3):

The JSF project stage is available by [`Application#getProjectStage()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/application/Application.html#getProjectStage--). The JSF application is in turn available by [`FacesContext#getApplication()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getApplication--). The JSF context is in EL available by `#{facesContext}`.

So, this should do in the error page:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{facesContext.application.projectStage eq 'Development'}">
         <!-- Print stack trace here -->
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
         <!-- Print custom message here -->
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```