# p:commandButton don't redirect when ExternalContext#redirect() is called

Tags: jsf, redirect, primefaces, commandbutton, exceptionhandler

Here's an example button which can throw an exception:

```
<h:commandButton value="save" update=":formTable:tableData">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="BTN_ONE"
        target="#{tamplateTableBean.buttonSelected}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

In my `ExceptionHandler` I have:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("error.xhtml");
```

When I use `<h:commandButton>` (as above example) and an exception occurs, then redirect is executed and error page is displayed.
When I use `<p:commandButton>`, then redirect is not happening (even though line `redirect("error.xhtml")` is executed) and it will stay on the same page as if nothing happened. The exception is caught in my `ExceptionHandler`, but JSF error page is not displayed.

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: The technical difference is that the PrimeFaces button sends an ajax request. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components

Answer (score 1):

As describe in link iIn BalusC comment - Omnifaces solve this problem. I remove my ExcetionHandler implementation and change to Omnifaces -> As in docs, I import omnifaces.jar, add to faces-config.xml

```
<factory>
  <exception-handler-factory>
     org.omnifaces.exceptionhandler.FullAjaxExceptionHandlerFactory
  </exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

and to web.xml

```
 <error-page> 
      <error-code>500</error-code> 
  <location>/faces/restricted/error.xhtml</location> 
 </error-page>
```

Now I catch exception in Ajax request and redirect to error page.
(tip: error.xhtml is facelet file and be careful to put correct path to it)