# Redirect in session bean @PostConstruct

Tags: jsf, redirect

I have a JSF 2.0 app that has a session bean that is accessed from home.xhtml, as follows:

```
@Named(value = "home")
@SessionScoped
public class Home implements Serializable{

@PostConstruct
    public void init() {
// Retrieve database data here
        try {
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("EXCEPTION");


        }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is, if the database retrieval fails, redirect to error.xhtml page. How is this done in the init method above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to manually mess with redirecting. Just throw the exception outright.

```
@PostConstruct
puclic void init() throws Exception { // Please be more specific, e.g. SQLException.
    // Retrieve database data here without try/catch block.
}
```

It will already end up in a HTTP 500 error page whose location (and thus the look'n'feel) can be customized by `web.xml`:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/errorpages/500.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

In case you'd like to also cover exceptions on ajax requests, head to this answer: [What is the correct way to deal with JSF 2.0 exceptions for AJAXified components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components/10451272#10451272)

Comment: @onepotato: Just stop stating assumptions. Ask a question and state the observations.

Comment: I will surely note that in my future interactions.

Comment: Hi @BalusC, can I use same approach to redirect back to login page if username or password is wrong? Or is there another more acceptable way to perform this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [External Context's](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) [`redirect(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#redirect%28java.lang.String%29) method.

```
FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
externalContext.redirect("page2.xhtml");
```