# JSF Handle Exception in Ajax events

Tags: ajax, jsf, exception, handle

I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10449862/what-is-the-correct-way-to-deal-with-jsf-2-0-exceptions-for-ajaxified-components)  and works perfectlly when a ViewExpiredException happen, but when i inspect (firefox utility) the view error redered, i see that its replacing it, but just inside the body tag of the normal view, i mean, the view which was the cause of the Exception. The view error had a css class declared in his own body tag, but i don't know, why doesn't replace the whole view error, instead just take all the content (after his body tag) of the view error and inserted inside the body tag of the normal view?

To get this behavior, i have a login view (normal view that i refer above) and just have to wait until session expire, then i try to login (submit the form of the view) and this trigger a ExceptionHandler to render de view error.

Here are some snippet:

login.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

  <h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
      <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    </f:facet>
    <title>PrimeFaces</title>
  </h:head>

  <h:body styleClass="login-body">
    <div class="login-panel ui-fluid">
      <div class="ui-g">
    <div class="ui-g-12 logo-container">
      <p:graphicImage name="images/logo-colored.png" library="theme-layout" />
      <h1>Login to Your Account</h1>
      <h2>WELCOME</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <p:inputText placeholder="User" />
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12">
      <p:password placeholder="Password" feedback="false"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 chkbox-container">
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="remember-me" />
      <p:outputLabel for="remember-me" value="Remember Me"/>
    </div>
    <div class="ui-g-12 button-container">
      <p:commandButton type="submit" value="Log in" icon="fa fa-user" styleClass="orange-btn" action="#{menu.login}" update="frmLoginPromo">
    </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-#{guestPreferences.layout}.css" library="theme-layout" />
  </h:body>

</html>
```

error.xhtml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head>
        <f:facet name="first">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
            <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        </f:facet>
        <title>PrimeFaces - Error </title>
    </h:head>

    <h:body styleClass="exception-body">
        <div class="exception-panel">
            <p:graphicImage name="images/icon-error.png" library="theme-layout" />

            <h1>Error Occured</h1>
            <p>An error occured, please try again later.</p>
        </div>

        <h:outputStylesheet name="css/layout-blue.css" library="theme-layout" />
    </h:body>

</html>
```

CustomExceptionHandler.java

```
    @Override
    public void handle() throws FacesException{
    final Iterator<ExceptionQueuedEvent> lclExceptionQueue = getUnhandledExceptionQueuedEvents().iterator();
    final FacesContext lclFacesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    final Map<String, Object> requestMap = lclFacesContext.getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
    while (lclExceptionQueue.hasNext()){
    ExceptionQueuedEvent event = lclExceptionQueue.next();
    ExceptionQueuedEventContext context = (ExceptionQueuedEventContext) event.getSource();
    Throwable lclThrowable = context.getException();


    try{
            if (lclThrowable instanceof ViewExpiredException){
 lclFacesContext.setViewRoot(lclFacesContext.getApplication().getViewHandler().createView(lclFacesContext, "/error.xhtml"));
                lclFacesContext.getPartialViewContext().setRenderAll(true);
                lclFacesContext.renderResponse();
            }
        }finally{
            lclExceptionQueue.remove();
        }
        }
        getWrapped().handle();
    }
```

Here is how looks like, after error view is rendered

[Inspecte view error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnLT3.png)
Please, tell me what am doing wrong?

Comment: Off-topic: You seem to be using PrimeFaces which has an Ajax exceptionhandler. Omnifaces (which you **should** use) has as well. why are you developing your own one?

Comment: @Kukeltje we just want to redirect to our error pages without showing all the stack to the enduser, we think that this stack its usefull only for developers and we already have it in the application server log.

Comment: I'm not asking what your goal/intention is, that is clear. I'm asking why you are developing your own Ajax exceptionhandler when both PrimeFaces and omnifaces provide one

Comment: can you try in a clean jsf project without PrimeFaces  (and what IS your PrimeFaces version and jsf implementation and x.y.z version?)

Comment: @Kukeltje  i didn't know it that Primefaces have his own handlerexception and moreover, this can handle both ajax and non ajax request. After that, i did some researching how to implement it and works like we want. Thanks for guide us to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are already using PrimeFaces, I'd opt for not developing your own exceptionhandlers. [PrimeFaces already has one that can handle both ajax and non-ajax requests](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/exceptionHandler.xhtml).

For the people not using PrimeFaces, I'd suggest to use the [OmniFaces exceptionhandling](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/exceptionhandlers/FullAjaxExceptionHandler)

For [PrimeFaces 6.2 the documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf) contains the information to configure this in chapter 11.3 (it is the same chapter btw for PF 6.1)

In summary (***ALL quotes are from the PF documentation)***

Configure an el resolver and the exceptionhandler

> ```
> <application>
>      <el-resolver>
>         org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver
>     </el-resolver>
> </application>
> <factory>
>     <exception-handler-factory>
>         org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory
>     </exception-handler-factory>
> </factory>
> ```

Configure errorpages if you want to in web.xml

> ```
> <error-page>
>     <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
>     <location>/ui/error/error.jsf</location>
> </error-page>
> <error-page>
>     <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
>     <location>/ui/error/viewExpired.jsf</location>
> </error-page>
> ```

You can then use information about the exceptions in EL in the error pages

> ```
> <h:outputText value="Message:#{pfExceptionHandler.message}" />
> <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}" escape="false" />
> ```

There is more info, for which I'd suggest to consult the documentation.

And for ajax exceptions you can do

> ```
> <p:ajaxExceptionHandler type="javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException"
>     update="exceptionDialog" onexception="PF('exceptionDialog').show();" />
> <p:dialog id="exceptionDialog" header="Exception: #{pfExceptionHandler.type} 
>     occured!" widgetVar="exceptionDialog" height="500px">
>     Message: #{pfExceptionHandler.message} <br/>
>     StackTrace: <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}" escape="false" />
>     <p:button onclick="document.location.href = document.location.href;"
>         value="Reload!"/>
> </p:dialog>
> ```

The configuration for OmniFaces is fairly similar.

**See also:**

- [Session timeout and ViewExpiredException handling on JSF/PrimeFaces ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203195/session-timeout-and-viewexpiredexception-handling-on-jsf-primefaces-ajax-request?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Ha, I'm using the OmniFaces handler.. didn't know PrimeFaces had one too!

Comment: @JasperdeVries: Off-topic: Tried OptimusFaces?

Comment: I've seen the project in Git, but haven't tried it yet.

Comment: Thanks again @Kukeltje.